# How convert timestamp in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

l am try to convert timeestamp coming from data json url

```
TimeFlight.text = list[position].TimeFlight.getDateTime(toString())
```

l am use list view in my app

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

    val view : View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false)


    val TimeFlight = view.findViewById(R.id.time_id) as AppCompatTextView
    val LogoAriline = view.findViewById(R.id.logo_image) as ImageView

    status.text= list[position].Stauts
    TimeFlight.text = list[position].TimeFlight.getDateTime(toString())
    Picasso.get().load(Uri.parse("https://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/static/images/data/operators/"+status.text.toString()+"_logo0.png"))
        .into(LogoAriline)



    return view as View
}

private fun getDateTime(s: String): String? {
    try {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
        val netDate = Date(Long.parseLong(s))
        return sdf.format(netDate)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        return e.toString()
    }
}
```

Data class for json

```
data class FlightShdu (val Airline : String ,val TimeFlight : String)
```

l used that code `getDateTime` but the format unknown

[image: see result image]

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead, precisely? If any error, post its complete and exact stack trace.

Comment: @JBNizet check my update

Comment: Is `TimeFlight` a string of the timestamp like `"1541480400"`?

Comment: @earthw0rmjim yes . `TimeFlight` is the string of the timestamp coming from data json url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `TimeFlight` is a stringified epoch timestamp (in milliseconds), you should pass that to your `getDateTime()` function:

```
TimeFlight.text = getDateTime(list[position].TimeFlight)
```

(if they are not millis but seconds, then simply multiply them by 1000 before passing them to the `Date` constructor)

On a side note, depending on the exact use case, creating a new `SimpleDateFormat` object might not be necessary on every `getDateTime()` call, you can make it an instance variable.

Also, i'd advise you to take a look at (and follow) the [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) for both Java and Kotlin applications.

Comment: @pabloescobar If you need the time, you may need something like `SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")` instead of `SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")`.

Comment: l really appreciate .

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the Date constructor take long as the milliseconds count since 1/1/1970 and the number you are getting is the seconds count.

my suggestion is the following code( you can change the formate):

```
const val DayInMilliSec = 86400000

private fun getDateTime(s: String): String? {
    return try {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
        val netDate = Date(s.toLong() * 1000 ).addDays(1)
        sdf.format(netDate)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.toString()
    }
}

fun Date.addDays(numberOfDaysToAdd: Int): Date{
    return Date(this.time + numberOfDaysToAdd * DayInMilliSec)
}
```

Comment: Hello Ahmed , can l change the code above to next date for tomorrow ?? l mean l get only the date for tomorrow via code above

Comment: so what i understood from your question is that you want the function to return the date of the next day that your function gets right ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun getDateTime(s: String): String? {
    return try {
        val date = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(Date(s.toLong()*1000))

        // current timestamp in sec
        val epoch = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000
        // Difference between two epoc
        val dif = epoch - s.toLong()
        val timeDif: String
        when {
            dif<60 -> {
                timeDif = "$dif sec ago"
            }
            dif/60 < 60 -> {
                timeDif = "${dif/60} min ago"
            }
            dif/3600 < 24 -> {
                timeDif = "${dif/3600} hour ago"
            }
            dif/86400 < 360 -> {
                timeDif = "${dif/86400} day ago"
            }
            else ->{
                timeDif = "${dif/31556926} year ago"
            }
        }
        "($timeDif) $date"

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).